# Remote access with Windows 10 IoT

Tags: remote, windows-iot

Is it possible to set up Windows 10 IoT with Raspberry Pi 3 so that I can login remotely (away from my local network)? The Web GUI is running on port 8080, so do I just need to forward that on the router?

What other ports / settings would you recommend to access the Pi remotely?

Comment: Thank you, I know how to forward ports I was just asking which ones to forward for Windows IoT. Is there a dyn dns built in in Windows IoT?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to connect to? But maybe we can make a wiki of common ports. Sounds like a good idea in the long ruin

Answer (score 1):

List of default ports that can be used on Windows IoT

- **8080** -  WebGUI (unencrypted)
- **22** - SSH to PowerShell
- ? - Remote Display
- ? - Visual Studio Debugging
- ? - AllJoyn

Comment: Is it possible to connect to WebGUI using some sort of encryption? Edge is telling me that the user + password will be send unencrypted.

Comment: VPN tunnel.... Yes I am afraid that everything via webgui is plain text and should not be used over the internet of ... you know.